# What is the variance of the number of heads that come up when a fair coin is flipped 10 times?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

So the answer to this is $5/2$.

I get that $E(x)=5$ which means that $\big(E(x)\big)^2 = 25$, therefore meaning that $E(x^2) = 55/2$.

How do I compute $E(x^2)$ in this scenario?

Comment: The distribution of X must come into play, at least partially. Do you know it?

Comment: I do not, can you explain please :)

Comment: OK, let us proceed backwards: how do you know that E(X)=5?

Comment: I know that E(x) =5 b/c theres a thm that states The expected number of successes when n mutually independent Bernoulli trials are per- formed, where p is the probability of success on each trial, is np.

Comment: Right. From this point, there are two venues: either another theorem gives the variance (this is what I would call the "black-box" approach), or one tries to understand where the first theorem is coming from and to deduce the variance version of this result (the "learning" approach). Since the black-box approach horrifies me, I would ask: why np?

Answer (score 7):

Note that $X = X_1 + \ldots + X_{10}$, where

$X_i=0$ if the $i$th flip is tails, and $1$ if the $i$th flip is heads.

Since the $X_i$'s are independent, we have

$Var(X) = Var(X_1 + \ldots + X_{10}) = Var(X_1) + \ldots + Var(X_{10})$.

Finally,

$Var(X_i) = E(X_i^2) - E(X_i)^2 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$,

so that

$Var(X_1) + \ldots + Var(X_{10}) = 10*(\frac{1}{4}) = \frac{5}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to work out the exact same problem for homework, here's my solution:

V(x) = E(x^2) - E(x)

As you stated, you know that E(x) = 5, which is true. I'll add the solution for that below.

For E(x^2) we need to take the value of each outcome and square it, then multiply it by its probability. Finally, they're all summed.

You need to do a binomial probability for all possible values of X, 0, 1, 2....., 10.

0:  0^2 * (10 choose 0) * (1/2)^10 * (1/2)^0

1:  1^2 * (10 choose 1) * (1/2)^9  * (1/2)^1

2:  2^2 * (10 choose 2) * (1/2)^8  * (1/2)^2

ect.....all the way up to 10:

10: 10^2 * (10 choose 10) * (1/2)^0 * (1/2)^10

These results are then all summed.

Note that that the powers of (1/2) will always work out to (1/2)^10, which is a common factor for each term.

This works out to be:[ 0*1 + 1*10 + 4*45 + 9*120 + 16*210 + 25*252 + 36*210 + 49*120 + 64*45 + 81*10 + 100*1 ] * (1/2)^10  =  27.5

27.5 - 25 = 2.5  =  5/2

You can do the exact same process as above to find E(x), just don't square the value of each outcome:

0:  0 * (10 choose 0) * (1/2)^10 * (1/2)^0

1:  1 * (10 choose 1) * (1/2)^9  * (1/2)^1

2:  2 * (10 choose 2) * (1/2)^8  * (1/2)^2

ect.....all the way up to 10:

10: 10 * (10 choose 10) * (1/2)^0 * (1/2)^10

This works out to be:[ 0*1 + 1*10 + 2*45 + 3*120 + 4*210 + 5*252 + 6*210 + 7*120 + 8*45 + 9*10 + 10*1 ] * (1/2)^10  =  5

Comment: Check out the following link to help formatting. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference